# Enable autoupdate SDK path between 2 PC on Android Studio 0.8.x

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

I have 2 computers: one with Windows 7 64 bit (home) and one with Windows 7 32 bit (office). Sometimes I need move my Android Studio from one PC to other PC.
The SDK is different between 2 PC:
on Windows 7 64 bit "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk";
on Windows 7 32 bit "C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk";

With Android Studio 0.6.x I didn't have problem because Android Studio asked me if I wanted to update the current SDK pth with real SDK path.

With Android Studio 0.8.x this function doesn't work anymore. When I move my project and open it with Android Studio, it doesn't ask me nothing so I have problem to working with it.

So, is there a way to enable this function again on Android Studio 0.8.1? In alternative how can I update the path of SDK on my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the SDK path on a per-project level by going to `File > Project Structure`, then selecting "SDK Location" from the left side of the window.

Assuming you are using version control of some sort, an easier way to accomplish what you want to do would be to add the `local.properties` file to your version control system's ignore list. This is the file that contains the SDK location setting and if this file isn't under version control, each computer can keep it's own copy and the IDE will take care of using the default.

Another alternative would be to move the SDK directory so it is in the same place on both computers. After doing so, you can update Android Studio to use the new directory for all projects by going to `File > Other Settings > Default Project Structure`.

Comment: The path on File > Project Structure is right ("File > Project Structure") but I get the same error when I try to run my app: "The SDK directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk' does not exist.". Besides run button (on toolbar) I have a android icon with red cross. If I try edit configuration I see: "androidmanifest.xml does not exist or has incorrect root tag" but androidmanifest.xml exist and the same manifest file works on my other PC.

Comment: One problem at a time- is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk` the correct path to your SDK on this machine?

Comment: No, my corret path on Office PC is "C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk" and on "File > Project Structure" I have "C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk"... the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk" is right on Home PC

Comment: I would check `local.properties` and make sure the path is right there. If not, update that file directly. If that's correct, perhaps update your office AS installation's default SDK and make sure that is also correct.

Comment: This works thanks. Of course, the automatic fix was much better.